# Existence of transverse homotopy between knots in a 3-manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, knot-theory, knot-invariants

I have a 3-manifold $\Sigma$ and two homotopic embedded knots $K_{0}(t): S^{1} \to \Sigma$ and $K_{1}(t): S^{1} \to \Sigma$. I wish to refine the homotopy between them to a "transverse homotopy" i.e, some $H(s,t)$ such that

- $s \in \{s_{0},\ldots,s_{n}\} \Rightarrow H(s,t)$ is a singular knot with one crossing i.e, there are only two points $t_{1},t_{2}\in[0,1]$ such that $H(s,t_{1})=H(s,t_{2})$.
- $s \in [0,1]\backslash \{s_{0},\ldots,s_{n}\} \Rightarrow H(s,t)$ is an embedded knot.

In definition 2.1 of [Type 1 knot invariants in 3-manifolds](https://msp.org/pjm/1998/183-2/pjm-v183-n2-p05-s.pdf) (bottom of page 5) the authors state that a transverse homotopy always exists between any two homotopic knots.

I'd like to know how to prove this statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $h : S^1 \times I \to \Sigma$ is a smooth homotopy between the knots $K_0 = h(-, 0)$ and $K_1 = h(-, 1)$. Consider the movie $f : S^1 \times I \to \Sigma \times I$ of the homotopy, defined by $f(x, t) = (h(x, t), t)$.

I claim that $f$ is homotopic, relative to it's boundary, to a map $g$ which is an immersion with transverse double points, i.e., $g$ is an embedding away from finitely many points $x_1, y_1, \cdots, x_n, y_n \in S^1 \times I$ such that $g(x_k) = g(y_k) = p_k$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$ and $\text{im} \,dg_{x_k} \pitchfork \text{im} \, dg_{y_k}$. This follows from a self-transversality theorem that I have stated and given a sketch of proof below.

As a matter of fact $g$ can be chosen to be $C^1$-close to $f$ as well. $f$ was completely horizontal to $\Sigma$, i.e., if we denote $f_t = f|S^1 \times \{t\}$ to be the restriction on the $t$-slice, $f_t' \subset (d\pi)^*T\Sigma$ where $\pi : \Sigma \times I \to \Sigma$ is the projection. Therefore $g_t (=g|S^1 \times \{t\})$ must be $\varepsilon$-horizontal to $\Sigma$, and in particular, $g_t' \notin \ker d\pi$. This would mean $\pi \circ g_t$ is an immersion for all $t \in I$.

Note that this is almost enough for what you want: Take $H = \pi_\Sigma \circ g$ to be your new homotopy. This is a homotopy of $K_0$ to $K_1$ through immersions, and the only difficulty is that $H_t$ might stay on a singular knot for an interval's worth of time $t \in J \subset I$, whereas you want it to stay there for only finitely many points in $I$. Locally near a crossing, $(H_t)_{t \in I}$ would look like a pair of undercrossing-overcrossing which gradually grows closer, stays in the position of "$\mathsf{X}$" for the interval $t \in J$ and then grows apart and becomes a pair of overcrossing-undercrossing. We modify $H$ near those points so that it only stays like an "$\mathsf{X}$" for a point $t = t_0 \in J$. Then further modify $H$ so that double points are introduced one at a time, i.e, $H_t$ has at most one double point.

---

Suppose $M$ is a compact $n$-manifold and $N$ is a compact $2n$-manifold. Let $C^\infty(M, N)$ be the space of smooth maps and $\text{Imm}(M, N)$ be the subspace of such maps which are immersions.

Call a map $f \in \text{Imm}(M, N)$ to be an immersion with clean double points if whenever $x, y \in M$, and $f(x) = f(y) = p$, there exists charts $U, V$ around $x, y$ respectively such that $f|_U, f|_V$ are embeddings, $f(U)$ intersects $f(V)$ transversely, and $f(U) \cap f(V) = \{p\}$. Denote the subspace of such maps as $\text{Imm}_{\pitchfork}(M, N)$

Theorem (Self-transversality of maps): $\text{Imm}_\pitchfork(M^n, N^{2n})$ is dense in $C^\infty(M^n, N^{2n})$.

Let $J^1(M, N)$ be the space of $1$-jets of maps $M \to N$ and $\mathscr{S} \subset J^1(M, N)$ be the subset of $1$-jets of non-immersions. The space of $1$-jets is an affine bundle $M_{2n \times n}(\Bbb R) \to J^1(M, N) \to M \times N$ with fiber keeping track of the formal derivative component. Let $\Sigma_{< n} \subset M_{2n \times n}(\Bbb R)$ be the stratified subset of matrices of rank strictly less than $n$. As $\mathscr{S}$ fibers over $M \times N$ with fiber $\Sigma_{< n}$, it is also a stratified subset of $J^1(M, N)$.

Given any map $f \in C^\infty(M, N)$, consider it's 1-jet prolongation $j^1 f : M \to J^1(M, N)$. By Thom transversality theorem, we can homotope $f$ by a $C^1$-small homotopy to $g \in C^\infty(M, N)$ such that $j^1 g \pitchfork \mathscr{S}$. But observe that $\dim J^1(M, N) = n(2n+3)$, so $\text{codim}\, j^1g(M) = \dim J^1(M, N)$ $- \dim M$ $=$ $2n(n+1)$ whereas $\text{codim}\, \mathscr{S}$ $=$ $\text{codim}_{M_{2n \times n}(\Bbb R)} \Sigma_{< n}$ $=$ $n+1$, so $\text{codim}\, j^1 g(M)$ $+$ $\text{codim}\, \mathscr{S}$ $>$ $\dim J^1(M, N)$, forcing $j^1 g$ to be disjoint from $\mathscr{S}$. This implies $j^1 g$ has rank $n$ everywhere, i.e., $g$ is an immersion.

This implies $\text{Imm}(M, N)$ is dense in $C^\infty(M, N)$. Now for any $f \in \text{Imm}(M, N)$ consider the map $F : M \times M \to N \times N$, $F(x, y) = (f(x), f(y))$. By a $C^1$-small homotopy we can modify $F$ to $G$ so that $G$ is transverse to the diagonal $\Delta_N \subset N \times N$. Let $G|\Delta_M$ be the restriction to the diagonal of $M \times M$. As $G$ is $C^1$-close to $F$, image of $G|\Delta_M$ fits inside an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $\Delta_N \subset N \times N$, and by $\epsilon$-neighborhood theorem we have a normal projection map to $\Delta_N$, with which we compose to get a map $g : M \to N$. $g \times g$ is $C^1$-close to $G$ near $\Delta_M$, and since $G \pitchfork \Delta_N$, by stability of transverse maps, $(g \times g) \pitchfork \Delta_M$ should hold as well. Therefore $g \in \text{Imm}_\pitchfork(M, N)$.

This implies we have a tower of successively dense subspaces $$\text{Imm}_\pitchfork(M, N) \subset \text{Imm}(M, N) \subset C^\infty(M, N)$$ 
In particular, $\text{Imm}_\pitchfork(M, N)$ is dense in $C^\infty(M, N)$, as required. (Note that for the above we need a relative-to-boundary version of this, but once $f$ is already an embedding restricted to (a collar neighborhood of) the boundary, we can do all the required homotopies fixing the boundary.)

Comment: So does this result only hold if $\Sigma$ is compact? Or are there analogues of the Thom transversality theorem for maps from compact n-manifolds to general 2n-manifolds?

Comment: @MikeKiss Compactness of the codomain is not necessary for transversality results to hold, no. Also note that my argument on the first bit is incomplete; I proposed a possible way to fix it. I'll think about it and see if it works.

Comment: Hi, sorry to revive this old question but there are some issues with the proof that I never managed to figure out. I can accept the existence of a map \tilde{F}: I \times S^{1} \to \Sigma \times I that is in general position but I am unsure why this implies that for fixed s \tilde{H}(s,\cdot) will be in general position.

Comment: For instance let's say \sigma = \tilde{H}(s,t_{1}) = \tilde{H}(s,t_{2}). Variation about s in T_{(s,t_{1})} I \times S^{1} and T_{(s,t_{2})} I \times S^{1} may produce orthogonal tangent vectors in T_{\sigma) \Sigma but variation about t in these tangent spaces may produce parallel tangent vectors in T_{\sigma) \Sigma. This outcome is perfectly consistent with \tilde{F} being in general position but violates \tilde{H}(s,\cdot) being in general position.

Comment: @MikeKiss It's been a while so you might have to help me remember the situation. As far as I recall my idea was to find a $g$ which is very close to the movie $f : I \times S^1 \to I \times \Sigma$ of the homotopy such that $g$ is an immersion with finitely many transverse double points. Now in particular that would mean on each slice $\{t\} \times S^1$, $g$ is the sort of knot you want: away from finitely many pairs of points it's an embedding (then modify a bit so that at most one pair of points can be problematic on each slice).

Comment: But this knot is in $I \times \Sigma$ not $\Sigma$, so the argument there was as it's an $\epsilon$-perturbation of $f$, which never kills anything along the $TI \subset T(I \times \Sigma)$ direction (ie vertical tangents), a small perturbation will also not do that. So compose $g$ with the projection $I \times \Sigma \to \Sigma$ and you get an immersed knot in $\Sigma$ as well, with at most one pair of points getting mapped to the same place. From a brief glance at your complaint, I feel that this epsilon-close argument resolves your problem. Feel free to explain it in more detail if not.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! As I understand it you have proven the following: Given $\tilde{F}(s,t) = ( \tilde{H}(s,t) , \tilde{pr_{1}}(s,t) ) \subset \Sigma \times I$ which has clean double points and has $\tilde{H}$ $\epsilon$-close to $H$ and $\tilde{pr_{1}}$ $\epsilon$-close to the projection map, the map $F^{\prime}(s,t) = ( \tilde{H}(s,t) , s)$ will also have clean double points. 
I agree with this. But knowing that $F^{\prime}(s,t)$ has clean double points doesn't necessarily ensure $\tilde{H}(s,t)$ has clean double points for each fixed s.

Comment: For instance consider a double point $(\sigma,s) = F^{\prime}(s,t_{1}) = F^{\prime}(s,t_{2})$. Since the double point is clean we know that $dF^{\prime}_{(s,t_{1})}(\dot{s})$, $dF^{\prime}_{(s,t_{1})}(\dot{t})$, $dF^{\prime}_{(s,t_{2})}(\dot{s})$ and $dF^{\prime}_{(s,t_{2})}(\dot{t})$ form a basis for the tangent space $T_{(\sigma,s)}(\Sigma \times I)$. We know that only $dF^{\prime}_{(s,t_{1})}(\dot{s})$ and $dF^{\prime}_{(s,t_{2})}(\dot{s})$ will have components in $T_{s}I$ direction but their components in $T_{\sigma}\Sigma$ could be orthogonal.

Comment: In this case the tangent vectors $dF^{\prime}_{(s,t_{1})}(\dot{t})$ and $dF^{\prime}_{(s,t_{2})}(\dot{t})$ could have parallel components in $T_{\sigma}\Sigma$ and this would be consistent with $(\sigma,s)$ being a double point. But in this case $\sigma$ is not a double point of $\tilde{H}(s,\cdot)$ since the tangent vectors at $t_{1}$ and $t_{2}$ will be parallel. 
Therefore we see that $F^{\prime}$ having clean double points does not necessarily mean that $\tilde{H}$ for fixed s will have clean double points.

Comment: @MikeKiss I see your complaint. In your original question you just wanted $H(s, -)$ to be immersed knots such that for all but finitely many $s$, they are embedded, and in those exceptional cases the immersed knots have at most one pair of double points. You didn't explicitly ask for clean double points, though (but I suppose that is what you intended by "crossing"). But nonetheless I think even that can be achieved, I'll ponder on how to do this for a while and get back to you.